# store user prefrences in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code for my ad system:

```
 function showandhide()
 {
    if ($('.showandhide').html() == 'show ads')
    {
       $('.showandhide').html("show ads");
       $('.ads').hide();
    }
    else 
    {
       $('.showandhide').html("hide ads");
       $('.ads').show();
    }
 }
```

The code is very simple. It hides and shows ads in my website. The problem is that it does not store the user preferences. How do I store them? Is there a fast way without using a database? I do not feel like creating a code to store information to my database just for hiding and showing ads. Is there any other fast solutions? maybe something in jQuery?

Comment: no, if you want to store anything, you have to use a database. You can use local storage, but that's still a type of database as well.

Comment: I would suggest dom local storage or cookies.

Comment: if you are trying to store the detail temporarily you can save it in session..!

Comment: Philemon philip Kunjumon I like your idea! do you have any documents or examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to store the detail temporarily you can save it in a session. for that you can use [`jquery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)..

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/update-session.php',
   data:"detail="+detail,
   type: 'post',
   success:function(data){
       // if you care. 
   }
});
```

**server side**

```
$_SESSION['pageX'] = $_POST['detail'];
```

**ADDITION**

in order to check if the session variable exists or not

check this link php [Session_id_registered](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php)

and you want to save the session only when you click a button. you can give that by using [jquery click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/)..

hope this helps!!

Comment: but my function will not work only by clicking on the button. 
I can see how to store it, but how do I recall it and let the function work again?

Comment: function will not work only by clicking on the button? What do u mean by that.? do you want to save the detail to the session on clicking on a button.?

Comment: yes.. but how can I recall those details? how do I check for that if they existed then something need to happen.

Answer (score 1):

[jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) allows you to store JavaScript objects in the user's web browser. It works in both recent browsers and in old versions of IE.

If you need to access the preference data from server-side code, consider setting a cookie instead using the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). The drawback is that setting a cookie slightly increases bandwidth usage, as the browser has to send it for each HTTP request.

Both of these allow you to avoid storing the data in a database on your server.